# C++/CLI with OpenCL in Visual Studio 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, c++-cli, opencl

First for all I would like to start by saying I am relatively new to openCL and kinda rusty in C++. Also this is the first time  I'm asking a question so feel free to correct me or point to something I could improve in the post.

I am interested in creating a project that will create mixed mode assembly dll (CLR Library Project) to be loaded and used by CLR Form applications. The DLL is importing the openCL static library c++ header files (native code) and using a managed wrapper class to use to expose it to the CLR.

However I keep falling into the pitfall of fatal error C1001 which really isn't much to go through.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include\cl\cl.hpp(1270): warning C4290: C++ exception      specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include\cl\cl.hpp(3708): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
1>To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
```

Which points to

```
cl_int enqueueNativeKernel(
void (CL_CALLBACK *userFptr)(void *),
```

I am using amd APP SDK v2.6 with the openCL 1.2 specs,Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and linking the header/lib provided by the SDK. In theory the crossing from unmanaged to unmanaged code shouldn't be an issue buut since it's compiled with /CLR I included the #pragmas to indicate the unmanaged passing anyway

```
#pragma once
#pragma managed(push,off)
#define __NO_STD_STRING
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR
#include <cl\cl.hpp>

#pragma comment(lib,"OpenCL.lib")
#pragma managed(pop)

//rest of code
```

Always with the dreadful C1001 error,and a Compiler Crash(CL.exe because of c1xx.dll)  and no matter how I play with the switches I am at a loss.

Switches are as follows /CLR, /MDd, Optimisation Disabled, EHa for Exception handling. And removing #defines or any of the wrapping code does't change a thing nor removing the #pragmas.

I should note that the project compiles fine with the C API included instead (CL\cl.h) and I know I could use that instead.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Or am I doing something terribly wrong?I would really appreciate some info on the matter.

Comment: Something you can try is to use OpenCL from unmanaged code compiled without `/clr`, and link that with your managed code.  The easiest way to do this is with a static library containing the unmanaged code, and use a project dependency to pull this into the managed project.

Comment: Possibly related: [Target .NET 3.5 C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106163/target-net-3-5-c-cli-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-2) In particular, follow the advice to clean all temporary files from your project, and ensure that you're targeting the correct version of the .NET Framework. Also see: [C1001 - Compiler crash on C++/CLI project in VS2010 when target framework is 3.5](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560606/c1001-compiler-crash-on-c-cli-project-in-vs2010-when-target-framework-is-3-5)

Comment: @CodyGray I have tried that, however there was no change. And I always made sure it was targeting net 4.0 actually.The issue can be easily reproduced. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @BenVoigt - For what it is worth, that is what I do to get around this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internal compiler error means that your compiler has *crashed*. It didn't find an error in your code; the compiler itself *broke*. This is due to a bug in the compiler, but if your code is wrong, then that could have helped trigger the bug.

Since "your code" in this case is not really *your* code, but OpenCL's code, it may just be that it can't be compiled by the C++/CLI compiler.

Comment: That's probably true. I was having similar thoughts on that. Maybe I should clarify by saying that I wonder if anyone has seen that before and knows what the hell is wrong with the c++ header that causes the compiler to crash. Since it has no issue whatsoever with the pure C API, I wondered if it could be solved with a preprocessor directive that I missed or don't know about. The header is open source anyway so anyone can have a look at it.

Thanks for the help anyway :) Makes me wonder if Microsoft would have a better answer.